# gensim corpus from sparse matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim

I have a data frame like this

```
import pandas as pd
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

tmp = pd.DataFrame({"word":  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    "house": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    "tree":  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], # occurred twice
                    "car":   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                    "food":  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                    "train": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]})
mydict = gensim.corpora.Dictionary()
```

from this, I want to create a `gensim` corpus.

I have tried `mycorp = [mydict.doc2bow(col, allow_update=True) for col in tmp.columns]` but the resulting corpus seems to not have been properly created:

> TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string

Can someone help me with this? I would like the resulting dictionary to represent the fact that word "tree" occurred twice in this data frame (i.e. the sum of the column).

Comment: What is the value of `doc`? You probably mean `mycorp = [mydict.doc2bow([col], allow_update=True) for col in tmp.columns]`

Comment: you're right. This is what I meant - and it yields an error message -  I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to `mydict.doc2bow` doesn't seem to be correct. It takes a list of strings, not a single string. The list of strings being the document.

### Scenario 1

If you consider each column name to be a document (i.e. document 1 is `["word"]`), then you could do:

```
[mydict.doc2bow([col], allow_update=True) for col in tmp.columns]
# [[(0, 1)], [(1, 1)], [(2, 1)], [(3, 1)], [(4, 1)], [(5, 1)]]
```

These are six documents (each sublist) with only a single word. The tuples in the sublist indicate the `(word_id, frequency)`. So the first document contains `word0` once. The second document contains `word1` once, etc.

### Scenario 2

If you consider your column names to be a single document, then you could do:

```
mydict.doc2bow(tmp.columns, allow_update=True) 
# [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
```

Where your corpus consists of a single document, which contains `word0` to `word5` all once

### Little bit of background

Instead of working with strings ("tokens") directly, like "word", "house", etc, `gensim` uses integers that represent a string. These integers are word ids. To see which word corresponds to which id, you can use:

```
mydict.token2id['word']
# 0
```

The bag of words is represented as a tuple with `(word_id, frequency)`, because any given word may occur multiple times in a document. Especially in longer documents, a single word may appear 100 times.

Instead of saving a reference to that word a 100 times, gensim is clever and saves `(word_id, 100)` instead. This then represents that some word occurs 100 times in a document.

Comment: Thank you. Using Scenario 1, I would like to use the weighing implied in the matrix: "tree" has occurred twice - and I would like to have this represented in the dictionary; (how) can I achieve that?

Comment: Since you are referring to `tmp.columns`, you actually only have "tree" in your 'corpus' once, because you cannot have duplicate column names. If you use `doc=["tree", "tree", "word", "house"]` in `mydict.doc2bow(doc)`, you can then see how often a given word occurs in your corpus by using `mydict.cfs`, which gives a dictionary with key being the word id and the value being the number of occurrences in your corpus

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but for the problem you are describing, the only relevant part of your input is `['word', 'house', 'tree', 'car', 'food', 'train']`

Comment: Thanks. And is there a way to process the above matrix as `doc1 = ["word"], doc2 = ["house"], doc3 = ["tree", "tree"]` etc.?

Comment: Yes, `doc = [doc1, doc2, doc3]` and then `yourdict = Dictionary(doc)` and `yourdict.cfs`